# Having 4 callback functions

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a code where I need 4 callback functions  (4 subscribers) for each wheel of my robot. What will be the best option to create those subscribers?

My idea was to create 4 threads that can run simultaneously:

```
ros::MultiThreadedSpinner spinner(4);
```

But from my understanding, the spinner will be blocking one and 4 threads won't use callbacks at the same time so I might just use a regular `spinOnce();`, am I correct?

Can you suggest may be something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322092/having-4-callback-functions/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The regular `ros::spin()` can handle multiple ROS topic subscribers. Just set up four subscribers in your `main` function and call `ros::spin()`:

```
ros::Subscriber sub1 =  nh.subscribe("topic1", 1, callback1);
ros::Subscriber sub2 =  nh.subscribe("topic2", 1, callback2);
ros::Subscriber sub3 =  nh.subscribe("topic3", 1, callback3);
ros::Subscriber sub4 =  nh.subscribe("topic4", 1, callback4);
ros::spin();
```

Just make sure your callback functions don't block or take a long time to finish, or your other callbacks won't get scheduled properly.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-05-01**:
@robustify If I have 4 wheels, wouldn't it make my wheels to start async? Meaning that I can get a bit different trajectory because some wheels start considerably quicker than others?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-01**:
If the callbacks don't take too long (and they shouldn't) there should be at most a few milliseconds between the callbacks. That sort of delay typically "drowns" in delays introduced by motion controllers, velocity ramp-up profiles and general sluggishness due to inertia, etc.